# Auto suggest using another textfield using JQuery in PHP

Tags: autosuggest

I am looking for auto suggest jquery script for php to get the result identifying from another field. Example:
user has to enter the address twice in two fields. If user enter the same address in second field it should suggest the same address which he enters above. is that possible ?

```
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="some area, some city, some country" />

<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value="above area, above city, above country" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the autocomplete source for #address2 dynamically.

Try this:

```
$("#address2").autocomplete();
$('#address2').focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("option", {
        source: [$('#address1').val()]
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n59sF/

Comment: it's not getting #address1 value